# How do I shift rows of consecutive numbers. Python 3.3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently making a calendar in python 3.3.2.  Right now I have

```
def month_28():
    if day == 1:
        columns = 7
        for i in range(1, 29):
            if i % columns != 0:
                print(i, end= " ")
                if i <= 9:
                    print(end="    ")
                else:
                   print(end="   ")
            else:
                print(i)
```

which prints

```
February 2013
Sun   Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri   Sat
1     2     3     4     5     6     7
8     9     10    11    12    13    14
15    16    17    18    19    20    21
22    23    24    25    26    27    28
```

but, if Jan. ends on a Wednesday, I need Feb to start on Thursday.  All the way through a year.  Any idea on how I can shift February 1 over 5 places and have it start counting on Thursday?  If there is a better way to print consecutively increasing numbers for each month in a year.  Let me know please.  Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use Calendar:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> print calendar.TextCalendar().formatmonth(2013,2,4)
          February 2013
Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat  Sun
                      1    2    3
  4    5    6    7    8    9   10
 11   12   13   14   15   16   17
 18   19   20   21   22   23   24
 25   26   27   28
```

If you want Sunday as the first day:

```
>>> print calendar.TextCalendar(calendar.SUNDAY).formatmonth(2013,2,4)
          February 2013
Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat
                           1    2
  3    4    5    6    7    8    9
 10   11   12   13   14   15   16
 17   18   19   20   21   22   23
 24   25   26   27   28
```

Conceptually, a calendar is a table; and a table is a textual representation of a list of lists:

```
>>> table=[['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
...        ['','','','','','1','2'],
...        ['3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
...        ['10','11','12','13','14','15','16'],
...        ['17','18','19','20','21','22','23'],
...        ['24','25','26','27','28','','']]
```

If you want to 'pretty print' that table into a calendar, you will need to roll your own:

```
def printTable (tbl, borderHorizontal = '-', borderVertical = '|', borderCross = '+'):
    cols = [list(x) for x in zip(*tbl)]
    lengths = [max(map(len, map(str, col))) for col in cols]
    f = borderVertical + borderVertical.join(' {:>%d} ' % l for l in lengths) + borderVertical
    s = borderCross + borderCross.join(borderHorizontal * (l+2) for l in lengths) + borderCross
    rtr=[s]

    for row in tbl:
        rtr.append(f.format(*row))
        rtr.append(s)

    return '\n'.join(rtr)

print(printTable(table))
```

Prints:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Sun | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |   1 |   2 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   3 |   4 |   5 |   6 |   7 |   8 |   9 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  10 |  11 |  12 |  13 |  14 |  15 |  16 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  17 |  18 |  19 |  20 |  21 |  22 |  23 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  24 |  25 |  26 |  27 |  28 |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm not answering the direct question but, still, don't you want to use the [`calendar`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html) module?

Anyway, the `weekday` method in class `date` of module [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) will be useful, if you insist in doing it by hand.  It returns a number from 0 to 6, which is exactly the number of places that you need to shift.  But your double `for` loop will need work...

Comment: I would but I am in intro to comp prog at my university. We are asked to make a calendar that asked for a year and day and displays accordingly.  Since we are in intro, she expects the calendar to look like a noobie did it.  The calendar module is too neat for us and we do not learn programming from it. =/

Comment: OK, then I'm not helping anymore...  Cheers...  :-)

Comment: Right on! Just need to get started =) not an answer key.. That is no fun and will not help me one bit.. Thanks!